# laravel - get parameters from http request

Tags: php, angularjs, http, laravel-5

I want to pass in multiple parameters from my Angular app to my Laravel API, namely the `id` and `choices` array supplied by user.

**Angular:**

http request:

```
verifyAnswer: function(params) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/api/questions/check',
        cache: true,
        params: {
            id: params.question_id,
            choices: params.answer_choices
        }
    });
```

**Laravel 5:**

routes.php:

```
$router->get('/api/questions/check/(:any)', 'ApiController@getAnswer');
```

ApiController.php:

```
public function getAnswer(Request $request) {
    die(print_r($request));
}
```

I thought I should use `:any` within my URI to indicate I'll be passing in an arbitrary amount of parameters of various data structure (id is a number, choices is an array of choices).

How can I make this request?

---

> [200]: /api/questions/check?choices= choice+1 &choices= choice+2 &choices= choice+3 &id=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change this:

```
$router->get('/api/questions/check/(:any)', 'ApiController@getAnswer');
```

to

```
$router->get('/api/questions/check', 'ApiController@getAnswer');
```

And fetch the values with

```
echo $request->id;
echo $request->choices;
```

in your controller. There is no need to specify that you will receive parameters, they will all be in `$request` when you inject `Request` to your method.

Comment: Btw, see above edit. It's making the request with each param in the choices array as its own URI param. Is there anyway to just pass through the array and loop through it in Laravel? What I want to do is get the question by ID, loop through the user choices, and check if the choice matches.

Comment: should be an array, isn't it one? @Growler

Comment: You may also retrieve all of the input data as an associative array using input method:

print_r($request->input());

Comment: I'd have to disagree. From a technical aspect, you CAN do this -- but I'm not sure it is worth what you lose in maintainability/readability. What if you have a large codebase and another developer wants to quickly scan the routes file to see what params a URL accepts?

Answer (score 35):

**Update for Laravel 8:**

Sometimes you may want to pass in parameters without using query strings.

EX

```php
Route::get('/accounts/{accountId}', [AccountsController::class, 'showById'])
```

In your controllers method, you can use a Request instance and access the parameters like so using the route method:

```php
public function showById (Request $request)
{
  $account_id = $request->route('accountId')
  
  //more logic here
}
```

But if you still wanted to use some query params then you can use that same Request instance and just use the query method

```php
Endpoint: https://yoururl.com/foo?accountId=4490
```

```php
 public function showById (Request $request)
{
  $account_id = $request->query('accountId');
  
  //more logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Routes:

```
1. /api/welcome
2. /api/blueprints/{blueprint_id}
3. /api/blueprints/{blueprint_id}/decorators/{decorator_id}
```

Middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->route()->hasParameter('blueprint_id')) {
        return response('This area needs blueprint_id parameter.', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }

    $blueprintId = $request->route()->parameter('blueprint_id');
    
    $request->merge(['blueprint_id' => $blueprintId]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Results:

```
1. [400] This area needs blueprint_id parameter.
2. [200]
3. [200]
```

Comment: You can use route model binding here and automatically return a 404 here if the blueprint_id is absent